# Move the absolute value in limits

Tags: limits

Is it true that I can pull out the absolute value in a limit such that: $|\lim_{x\to a} f(x)|=\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)|$. Both quantities are non-negative and I can't see how moving the operator would change the value of the limit, but maybe there is a counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counterexample can be made if the left limit does not exist.

For example, take $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\in\mathbb Q\\ -1 & x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

Then, clearly, $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$$ does not exist (and so neither does $$\left|\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\right|$$
but on the right, $$\lim_{x\to 0} |f(x)| = \lim_{x\to 0} 1 = 1$$

---

However, if the limit exists, then yes, the equality holds (because $x\mapsto |x|$ is a *continuous* function).

Answer (score 0):

A simple counter-example is:
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
1 & \mbox{if }\; x \ge 0 \\
-1 & \mbox{if }\; x < 0 \\
\end{array}\right.$$
because then:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) = 1 \quad \mbox{and} \quad \lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x) = -1$$
so $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ doesn't exist (and hence $|\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$| doesn't exist), but:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} |f(x)| = \lim_{x \to 0} 1 = 1$$